# How to use Stephanus numbers?

Tags: plato

A technical question here. I'm new to Plato and want to learn how to cite using Stephanus numbers. I'm a little confused because I'm not sure if the numbers are accurate to the line from translation to translation.

So for example, if I have something in between two pages like in the picture, do I cite it like this: "the expertise of the king with that of the interpreter" (Statesman, 260d-e)?

Or what if I just want to cite "that of the interpreter", is it still (Statesman, 260d-e) or can I just cite (Statesman 260e), or do both work?

[image]

Like this?

Answer (score 1):

I would quote it as "Plt. 260d11-e1", but "Plt. 260d-e" is also OK.